# How to create the corda.jar?

Tags: corda

When I build the corda project locally, I find a `corda-4.1-corda.jar`. Is that basically the same as the `corda.jar` file produced when node directories are generated by the cordformation plugin? Can I replace the latter by the former, after renaming it, in a deployment?

Answer (score 2):

Once your dependencies are set correctly, you can build your CorDapp JAR(s) using the Gradle jar task

Unix/Mac OSX: ./gradlew jar
Windows: gradlew.bat jar

Answer (score 0):

Run `./gradlew clean build -x test` from the root directory. Once the process finishes, the jar is produced in the `corda/node/capsule/build/libs/` directory as `corda-<version>.jar`.